# VB.net An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll Format of the initialization string does not conform

Tags: vb.net

in VB.net  error
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

```
Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-58360NG; database=myenergy; Integrated Security-true")
```

Comment: The issue is clearly a typo that you failed to notice. We all do that from time to time but this is one that you should have been able to fix anyway. If you were told that the connection string was wrong but couldn't work out why then you should have deleted the whole thing and written it from scratch. If you'd done that then you'd have been unlikely to make the same mistake again. If you had commented out that line and rewritten it then you'd have seen the difference. Even with no programming experience, you should still be able to apply logic to problem solving.

Answer (score 2):

`Integrated Security-true` should be `Integrated Security=true`